# How to show the latest email from each sender (get top 1 row from each group)?

Tags: indexeddb

I want to manage the list of emails in a typical email Inbox using `indexedDB`. Each email has just three properties:

1. `Time` - time email was received
2. `Sender` - email address of sender
3. `Subject` - the title of the email

How should I model the data in `indexedDB` and how should I formulate the queries to achieve the following:

1. List the latest email from each `Sender` (Time, Sender, Subject), ordered by the `Time` (descending order) of each latest email. This list shows one email, the latest, from each `Sender`.
2. Given a `Sender`, list all emails from this `Sender`, ordered by `Time`.

I am totally new to NoSql. I think I can achieve the second query relatively easily by creating an index for `Sender` and then opening a cursor for the index.

For the first query, I was thinking of maintaining a separate store, `Latest`, which keeps the latest email from each sender. Every time a new email is received, it has to be `Put` into `Latest`. Obviously, this is fraught with problems and I need help on the "proper" way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Using an IndexedDB wrapper [JsStore](http://jsstore.net/) you can create a table for storing mails with an autoincrement column (say Id) and use this column(Id) to sort the data.

**Staring with the case #2:**

For retrieving all the emails from a sender

```
var Connection = new JsStore.Instance("Database_name");
Connection.select({
    From: "Inbox", // Inbox is your table name
    Where:{
        Sender: sender_email
    },
    Order: {
        By: "Id",
        Type: "desc"
    },
    OnSuccess:function (results){
        console.log(results);
    },
    OnError:function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

**case #1:**

It would be very easy to retrieve the latest email for each sender if we could use GROUP BY clause in JsStore but unfortunately It is not provided in the current version of JsStore but it will probably be supported with its [next release](https://github.com/ujjwalguptaofficial/JsStore/issues/2).

Till then we can filter the mails on full record or can fetch one by one using sender's email id.

*Filtering on full record*:

```
var Connection = new JsStore.Instance("Database_name");
Connection.select({
    From: "Inbox", // Inbox is the table name
    Order: {
        By: 'Id',
        Type: "desc"
    },
    OnSuccess:function (results){
    var sendersName = [];
    var filteredMails = results.filter(function(mail){
        if(sendersName.indexOf(mail.sender) == -1){
            sendersName.push(mail.sender);
            return mail;
        }
    });
    console.log(filteredMails);
    },
    OnError:function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

*Fetch latest mail for each sender one by one and push into an array:*

```
var mails=[];
senders_email.forEach(function(value){  // keep the list of senders email in the array "sender_email"
    Connection.select({
        From:'Inbox',
        Where:{
            Sender:value
        },
        Limit:1,
        Order: {
            By: 'Id',
            Type: "desc"
        },
        OnSuccess:function(result){
           result.length > 0 && mails.push(result[0]);
        },
        OnError:function(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
    })
});
```

You can have a look on its sql type syntax for querying with IndexedDB on its [official site](http://jsstore.net/Tutorial/).It will be then easy for you to interpret the above codes.

Answer (score 0):

As a guess, it would involve using indices based on multiple properties. It is a bit counter-intuitive and tough to get right at first, but essentially:

```
function onupgradeneeded(event) {
  // ... 
  // make sure to use explcit and exact property names in second 
  // param to createIndex
  store.createIndex('sender-time', ['sender', 'time']);
}

function get_latest() {
  // ...
  var index = store.index('sender-time');

  // use prev so that the sort order is descending instead of 
  // ascending
  // first arg is the range, we are not limiting items in any way 
  // here, at least explictly. implicitly we are filtering out items
  // without a sender or without a time since missing values cause 
  // the object to be excluded from the index.
  var request = index.openCursor(null, 'prevunique');

  request.onsuccess = function() {
    // This iterates over all items. The trick then is to advance the 
    // cursor to the prev unique item. Since items in the index are 
    // ordered first by sender, then by time, jumping to prev unique 
    // sender skips over the other records for the same sender you 
    // would see if you normally just advanced the cursor.

  }
}
```

The worst case scenario is you load all items, then do all the filtering and sorting in memory. In comparison to the worst case, the above code reduces the number of objects deserialized (loaded from indexedDB into js land), and the items are already sorted, and nextUnique logic happens in C++ land instead of Js land so it evaluates much faster.

For case #2, you do a trick with the range parameter to openCursor. You no longer need to pass prev either if you want to sort time from oldest to newest.

```
function get_sender() {
  var index = store.index('sender-time');
  var lowerBound = ['sender-value-here', smallest date possible in js];
  var upperBound = ['the-same-sender-value-here', largest date possible in js];
   var range = IDBKeyRange.bounds(lowerBound, upperBound);
   // NOTE: above might be wrong I forget, you have to make the 
   // bounds inclusive, so that sender matches and the bounds do not 
   // result in excluding all records
   // again here you don't need 'prev' 2nd param unless you want 
   // reverse order
   var request = index.openCursor(range);
}
```

Essentially a sender-time index is kind of like a `SELECT * ORDER BY sender ASC, time ASC` intermediate result that you then scan. So in the first case you use nextUnique to simply jump to next new sender and get their first item and then skip again.  In the second case, you are restricting with a where clause like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE sender >= sender && sender <= sender && time >= min-time && time <= max-time`. But note this is a severe simplification. In reality we are exploiting the fact that we bypass the short-circuiting evaluation of the pseudo-where clause that goes in indexedDB that would cause everything to screw up if we has looser sender condition. But in this case sender is either not conditioned (secnario 1 where we just use sort order), or in case 2, sender is always the same sender and we know the first part of the boolean clause is always true so the second clause is always evaluated.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Would you consider keeping a separate store `Latest` as I described in my question a viable option?

Comment: Not unless that is the only way to do it. With nosql dbs you pursue and prefer performance over normal form.

Comment: Note, next or prev unique might not work actually because both sender and time are part of the key path. Maybe try using advance or continue on just sender instead if that is possible.